# Making a full width xAxis in d3.js v5 (timeScale)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data on how many words I publish every month.

[image: Dataset]

I want to make a bar chart. This is what I have right now.

[image: Curretn Bar Chart]

I want to make the xAxis full width and the ticks right below the center of the bar. I've tried numerous methods (inverting, clamping, shifting), but couldn't get it to work.

**xScale**

```js
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
        .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth * ((dataset.length - 1) / dataset.length)])
```

**xAxis**

```js
const xAxisGenerator = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)

const xAxis = bounds.append("g")
    .call(xAxisGenerator)
    .style("transform",`translateY(${dimensions.boundedHeight}px)`)
```

Thanks a ton for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I typically have to translate bars to sit midway over the x-axis ticks. If it's just a matter of the line extending further, here's a previous solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989524/extend-x-and-y-axis-length-in-scatterplot-d3js

Comment: Gerardo Furtado, thanks for pointing me to the question!