# D3 - How to extend x-axis without shifting ticks?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm having trouble finding a way to extend d3's x-axis to beyond the last tick. The reason I have the gap is because I'm rendering a bar chart, and I'd love for each bar to be centered around the tick (which is working nicely).

Is there a way to extend the x-axis to close the gap between the x-axis and the y-axis without shifting the positions of each tick?

I've created a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pine-kz6uf?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate the issue and here's a screenshot for convenience:

[image: image showing gap between x and y axis]

Comment: ugly but simple, you could extend the path element by updating the d attribute

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, but is there a reliable way to know the value of the `H` command should be?

Comment: I would think so, it should just depend on the scale you provide. I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989524/extend-x-and-y-axis-length-in-scatterplot-d3js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ee2Dev pointed out, we can add a new `<path />` for this.

D3 makes it as easy as:

```
d3.select(xAxisRef.current)
  .call(d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale))
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", `M0.5,6V0.5H916`)
  .attr("stroke", "currentColor");
```

See the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pine-kz6uf?file=/src/App.js)

The `M0.5,6V0.5H916` value is mostly copied from the other SVG path's draw command, and altered slightly using trial and error.